# onOptionsItemSelected(); calling more than two actions at once (same ID)

Tags: android, menuitem

I have a menu with actions that run custom methods, they are only called in each action, so they shouldn't be done at the same time. Problem is, with my code, any option clicked triggers too my action `"action_filtrar_hora", and I can't find why maybe it's the result of the boolean method`onOptionsItemSelected`?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_sign_out) {
        mAuth.signOut();
        mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
        //signOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(this,SignIn.class));
        finish();
    }
    if(id == R.id.action_cambiar_ciudad)
    {
        seleccionarCiudad();
    }

    if(id == R.id.action_cambiar_destino)
    {
        seleccionarDestino();
    }

    if(id == R.id.mis_viajes);
    {
        buildRecyclerView();
    }

    if(id == R.id.action_filtrar_hora)
    {
        dialogFiltrarHora();
    }
    if(id == R.id.action_punto_recogida_ida)
    {
        dialogEstablecerPuntoRecogidaIda();
    }

    if(id == R.id.action_punto_recogida_vuelta)
    {
        dialogEstablecerPuntoRecogidaVuelta();
    }
    return true;
}
```

While debugging, I found that these actions have different IDs, but they if seems to execute on both for some reason I can't understand, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to use switch case here .
But can you provide more details because this is not efficient to get what is happening in  your Application ! thanks

Comment: Yes, I was thinking in implementing the switch  when I got all my options created, maybe in this case it will fix it, I will now try. If that doesn't work, what do you think you need, the methods? I don't think they are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer was building a switch statement instead of multiple if's, but still makes no sense why it executed two actions at once.